# call rvalue-constructor from an lvalue-constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, overloading, rvalue-reference

I'd like to provide a constructor definition only once – for both lvalue and rvalue.

```
class A;

class B {
    B(A const& a): B(A(a)) {}
    B(A&&);
};
```

Is `B::B(A&&)` guaranteed to be called by `B::B(A const&)`?

Comment: Well, the above doesn't compile, as `A` is not defined?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using perfect forwarding instead?

Comment: This is equivalent to defining only `B(A)`. Save yourself some keystrokes.

Comment: @Casey: It isn't, though nearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you are delegating to a constructor with a single temporary argument of type `A`, an rvalue which is an xvalue.